# Почему долго открывается форма?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
  private void StaffPrint_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (LoginDBEntities db = new LoginDBEntities())
        {
            IPagedList<staff> list = db.staffs.OrderBy(p => p.id_staff).ToPagedList(currentPage, pageSize);
            btnNext.Enabled = list.IsFirstPage;
            btnPrevious.Enabled = list.IsLastPage;
            lblPageNumber.Text = string.Format("Page {0}/{1}", list.PageNumber, list.PageCount);
            staffBindingSource.DataSource = list.ToList();
        }
    }
```

При нажатии на меню проходит порядка 5-8 сек, хотя с остальными формами все норм.
Почему долго открывается форма ?

Comment: Потому что вы в коде работы с формой читаете из базы данных?

Comment: Логика должна быть "Показали форму" - "В отдельном потоке подгружаете данные" - "Для удобства отобразили "Загрузка..." - "После вывода отображаете данные". У вас сейчас если я не ошибаюсь загрузка данных в том же потоке и при загрузке формы. Что в итоге и дает эти 5-8 сек..

Comment: Уроки с Ютуба ((( Спасибо

Comment: @VictorRadin: Вы бы лучше книги читали. На ютубе ничего хорошего нет.